# Node server process working on Ubuntu server but not home Ubuntu PC localhost

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, localhost, port, firewall

I am working on a small MMO which is currently serving on a remote Ubuntu server I setup. After I fixed a problem with the local Node version, the server process now runs fine on my home computer but nothing comes up in localhost (except for initially an Apache default page, but I closed the Apache process to stop it blocking port 80). I am running the code using `node server.js` (well, `forever server.js` in the server, but for these purposes it's the same). Code as follows:

**server.js**

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function (suffix)
{
    return (this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1);
}

String.prototype.startsWith = function (prefix)
{
    return (this.substr(0, prefix.length) == prefix);
}

String.prototype.contains = function (toSearch)
{
    return (this.indexOf(toSearch) != -1);
}

Array.prototype.inArray = function (obj)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        if (this[i] == obj)
            return true;
    return false;
}

Array.prototype.append = function (arr)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        this[this.length] = arr[i];
}

String.prototype.leftPad = function (char, length)
{
    var result = this;
    while (result.length < length)
    {
        result = char + result;
    }

    return result;
}

String.prototype.hashPassword = function (salt)
{
    var crypto = require('crypto');
    return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(salt + this).digest('base64');
}

var nextPlayerId = 1;

var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
    url = require("url"),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app, { log: false }),
    path = require("path"),
    fs = require('fs');
var zlib = require('zlib');
var config = require('./config');

GLOBAL.secureKey = config.secureKey;

io.enable('browser client minification');

io.sockets.on('connection', socketHandler);

var knownExt = [
    ['.html', 'text/html'],
    ['.js', 'text/javascript'],
    ['.css', 'text/css'],
    ['.png', 'image/png'],
    ['.jpg', 'image/jpeg'],
    ['.gif', 'image/gif'],
    ['.mp3', 'audio/mpeg'],
    ['.ogg', 'audio/ogg'],
    ['.dae', 'text/plain']
];

var moduleDirs = ['modules/', 'admin/', 'object_codes/', 'block_codes/', '3dgeometry/'];
var worldGenModuleDirs = ['special_areas/', 'world_details/'];

GLOBAL.getDb = function ()
{
    var mongodb = require("mongodb"),
        mongoserver = new mongodb.Server("localhost", 27017, {});
    return new mongodb.Db(config.dbName, mongoserver, {safe: true});
}

GLOBAL.after_login = new Array();
GLOBAL.after_disconnect = new Array();
GLOBAL.socketFunctions = new Array();
GLOBAL.socketFunctions[GLOBAL.socketFunctions.length] = {name: 'ping', action: function (socket, data)
{
    socket.pingDate = new Date();
}};
GLOBAL.socketFunctions[GLOBAL.socketFunctions.length] = {name: 'position', action: socketPositionUpdate};
GLOBAL.socketFunctions[GLOBAL.socketFunctions.length] = {name: 'disconnect', action: function (socket, data)
{
    var playerId = socket.playerId;
    //socket.broadcast.emit('player_disconnect', {playerId: socket.playerId});
    // Remove useless sockets
    for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL.sockets.length; i++)
    {
        if (playerId == GLOBAL.sockets[i].playerId)
        {
            GLOBAL.sockets.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    /*for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL.sockets.length; i++)
     GLOBAL.sockets[i].emit('player_disconnect', {playerId: playerId});*/
    socket.broadcast.emit('player_disconnect', {playerId: playerId});
    for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL.after_disconnect.length; i++)
        GLOBAL.after_disconnect[i](socket);
}};

setInterval(checkTimeout, 1000);

GLOBAL.updatePositionFunctions = new Array();
GLOBAL.specialUri = new Array();

GLOBAL.sockets = new Array();

require('./user_storage.js');
require('./map_storage.js');
require('./general_data.js');
require('./wiki.js');
require('./chat.js');
require('./chat_bot.js');
require('./chat_bot_sentences.js');
require('./player_market.js');
require('./player_owned_areas.js');
require('./news.js');
require('./books.js');
require('./payment_done.js');

var baseDir = process.cwd();
if (baseDir.endsWith('server'))
{
    baseDir = path.resolve(baseDir, "..");
}

//console.log(baseDir);

function handler(request, response)
{
    var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

    if (uri == "/")
        uri = "/index.html"
    else if (uri == "/chat" || uri == "/chat/")
        uri = "/chat/index.html";

    for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL.specialUri.length; i++)
    {
        if (uri.substr(0, GLOBAL.specialUri[i].name.length) == GLOBAL.specialUri[i].name)
        {
            GLOBAL.specialUri[i].action(request, response);
            return;
        }
    }

    var filename = path.join(baseDir, uri);

    if (uri == "/index.html")
    {
        mainFile(request, response);
        return;
    }
    if (uri == "/welcome.html")
    {
        welcomeFile(request, response);
        return;
    }
    else if (uri == "/allModulesCode.js")
    {
        modulesCode(request, response);
        return;
    }
    /*else if (uri == "/cv.appcache")
     {
     manifestFile(request, response);
     return;
     }*/

    fs.exists(filename, function (exists)
        {
            var isOk = true;
            try
            {
                if (!exists)
                    isOk = false;
                else if (fs.statSync(filename).isDirectory())
                    isOk = false;
            }
            catch (err)
            {
                isOk = false;
            }

            if (uri.startsWith("/server/"))
                isOk = false;
            if (uri.contains("..") || uri.contains("./") || uri.contains("/."))
                isOk = false;

            if (!isOk)
            {
                response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
                response.write("404 Not Found\n");
                response.end();
                return;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < knownExt.length; i++)
            {
                if (filename.endsWith(knownExt[i][0]))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (filename.endsWith('.js') || filename.endsWith('.html'))
                        {
                            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": knownExt[i][1], "Expires": -1, "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "Pragma": "no-cache"});
                            fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(response);
                        }
                        else if (filename.endsWith('.css'))
                        {
                            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": knownExt[i][1], "Expires": -1, "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "Pragma": "no-cache"});
                            cssCode(filename, response);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": knownExt[i][1], "Cache-Control": "max-age=31536000", "Cache-Control": "public", "Expires": new Date(((new Date()).getTime() + 1000 * 31536000))});
                            fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(response);
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                        (ex)
                    {
                        console.log(ex)
                        response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
                        response.write("404 Not Found\n");
                        response.end();
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }

            response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            response.write("404 Not Found\n");
            response.end();
        }
    );
}

function modulesCode(request, response)
{
    response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/javascript", "Expires": -1, "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "Pragma": "no-cache" });

    response.write("var codeLines=[];");
    var nbLines = 1;

    var allDirs = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < moduleDirs.length; j++)
        allDirs[allDirs.length] = moduleDirs[j];
    for (var j = 0; j < worldGenModuleDirs.length; j++)
        allDirs[allDirs.length] = worldGenModuleDirs[j];

    for (var j = 0; j < allDirs.length; j++)
    {
        var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + '/' + allDirs[j]);
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            if (files[i].endsWith(".js"))
            {
                response.write("\n// ----------------------------\n");
                response.write("// " + allDirs[j] + "/" + files[i] + "\n");
                nbLines += 4;
                var data = fs.readFileSync(baseDir + '/' + allDirs[j] + "/" + files[i], "utf8");
                var dataLines = data.split('\n').length;
                response.write("codeLines[codeLines.length]={fromLine:" + nbLines + ",toLine:" + (nbLines + dataLines) + ",name:'" + allDirs[j] + "/" + files[i] + "'}\n");
                nbLines += dataLines;
                response.write("// ----------------------------\n");

                response.write(data);
            }
        }
    }

    response.write("\n\n// ----------------------------\n");
    response.write("// images dates\n");
    response.write("// ----------------------------\n");
    response.write("var imageVersion={};\n");
    var contentDirs = ['/images', '/3dmodels'];
    for (var j = 0; j < contentDirs.length; j++)
    {
        var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + contentDirs[j]);
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            var s = fs.statSync(baseDir + contentDirs[j] + '/' + files[i]);
            response.write("imageVersion['" + files[i] + "']='" + s.mtime.getTime() + "';\n");
        }
    }

    response.write("\n// ----------------------------\n");
    response.write("// Init\n");
    response.write("initialize();");

    /*var code = "";
     code += "var codeLines=[];";
     var nbLines = 1;

     var allDirs = [];
     for (var j = 0; j < moduleDirs.length; j++)
     allDirs[allDirs.length] = moduleDirs[j];
     for (var j = 0; j < worldGenModuleDirs.length; j++)
     allDirs[allDirs.length] = worldGenModuleDirs[j];

     //var path = require('path');

     var mustUpdated = true;
     if (fs.existsSync(baseDir + '/cache/allModulesCode.js'))
     {
     mustUpdated = false;
     var cacheFile = fs.statSync(baseDir + '/cache/allModulesCode.js').mtime.getTime();

     for (var j = 0; j < allDirs.length && mustUpdated == false; j++)
     {
     var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + '/' + allDirs[j]);
     for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
     {
     if (files[i].endsWith(".js"))
     {
     if (fs.statSync(baseDir + '/' + allDirs[j] + "/" + files[i]).mtime.getTime() >= cacheFile)
     {
     mustUpdated = true;
     break;
     }
     }
     }
     }
     }

     if (!mustUpdated)
     {
     //response.write(fs.readFileSync(baseDir + '/cache/allModulesCode.js', "utf8"));
     response.write(fs.readFileSync(baseDir + '/cache/allModulesCode.js.orig', "utf8"));
     response.end();
     return;
     }

     for (var j = 0; j < allDirs.length; j++)
     {
     var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + '/' + allDirs[j]);
     for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
     {
     if (files[i].endsWith(".js"))
     {
     code += "\n// ----------------------------\n";
     code += "// " + allDirs[j] + "/" + files[i] + "\n";
     nbLines += 4;
     var data = fs.readFileSync(baseDir + '/' + allDirs[j] + "/" + files[i], "utf8");
     var dataLines = data.split('\n').length;
     code += "codeLines[codeLines.length]={fromLine:" + nbLines + ",toLine:" + (nbLines + dataLines) + ",name:'" + allDirs[j] + "/" + files[i] + "'}\n";
     nbLines += dataLines;
     code += "// ----------------------------\n";

     code += data;
     }
     }
     }

     code += "\n\n// ----------------------------\n";
     code += "// images dates\n";
     code += "// ----------------------------\n";
     code += "var imageVersion={};\n";
     var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + '/images');
     for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
     {
     var s = fs.statSync(baseDir + '/images/' + files[i]);
     code += "imageVersion['" + files[i] + "']='" + s.mtime.getTime() + "';\n";
     }

     code += "\n// ----------------------------\n";
     code += "// Init\n";
     code += "initialize();";

     var UglifyJS = require("uglify-js");
     fs.writeFile(baseDir + '/cache/allModulesCode.js.orig', code+"\n\ncodeStyle='orig'\n", "utf8");
     var result = UglifyJS.minify(code+"\n\ncodeStyle='mini'\n", {fromString: true});
     var miniCode = result.code;
     fs.writeFile(baseDir + '/cache/allModulesCode.js', miniCode, "utf8");
     response.write(code+"\n\ncodeStyle='orig'\n");
     //response.write(miniCode);*/

    response.end();
}

function cssCode(filename, response)
{
    //fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(response);
    //console.log(filename)
    fs.readFile(filename, "utf8", function (err, fileData)
    {
        fileData = fileData;
        var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + '/images');
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            var r = new RegExp(files[i].replace(".", "\\."), "g");
            var s = fs.statSync(baseDir + '/images/' + files[i]);
            fileData = fileData.replace(r, files[i] + "?v=" + s.mtime.getTime());
        }
        //console.log(fileData)
        response.write(fileData);
        response.end();
    });
}

function mainFile(request, response)
{
    var filename = path.join(baseDir, "/index.html");
    //console.log(filename);

    fs.readFile(filename, function (err, fileData)
    {
        response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html", "Expires": -1, "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "Pragma": "no-cache" });

        var worldGenModules = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < worldGenModuleDirs.length; j++)
        {
            var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + '/' + worldGenModuleDirs[j]);
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            {
                if (files[i].endsWith(".js"))
                {
                    worldGenModules[worldGenModules.length] = worldGenModuleDirs[j] + files[i];
                    //modules[modules.length] = worldGenModuleDirs[j] + files[i];
                }
            }
        }

        //response.write(("" + fileData).replace("#title#", config.title).replace("'#modules#'", JSON.stringify(modules)).replace("'#worldGenModules#'", JSON.stringify(worldGenModules)));
        response.write(("" + fileData).replace("#title#", config.title).replace("'#worldGenModules#'", JSON.stringify(worldGenModules)));
        response.end();
    });
}

function sortByDate(a, b)
{
    if (a.date < b.date)
        return 1;
    if (b.date < a.date)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

/*function manifestFile(request, response)
 {
 response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/cache-manifest", "Expires": -1, "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "Pragma": "no-cache" });

 var dirs = [];
 dirs.append(moduleDirs);
 dirs.append(worldGenModuleDirs);
 dirs.append(["images/"]);

 var maxfs = 0;

 for (var j = 0; j < dirs.length; j++)
 {
 //console.log(baseDir + "/" + dirs[j])
 var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + "/" + dirs[j]);
 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
 {
 var s = fs.statSync(baseDir + '/' + dirs[j] + files[i]);
 var s = s.mtime.getTime();
 if (s > maxfs)
 maxfs = s;
 }
 }

 response.write("CACHE MANIFEST\n");
 response.write("# Version " + s + "\n");

 for (var j = 0; j < dirs.length; j++)
 {
 //console.log(baseDir + "/" + dirs[j])
 var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + "/" + dirs[j]);
 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
 {
 var s = fs.statSync(baseDir + '/' + dirs[j] + files[i]);
 var s = s.mtime.getTime();
 if (s > maxfs)
 maxfs = s;
 }
 }

 response.write("/index.html\n");
 response.write("/socket.io/socket.io.js\n");
 response.write("/lib/random.js\n");
 response.write("/lib/perlin.js\n");
 response.write("/main.js\n");
 response.write("/allModulesCode.js\n");

 for (var j = 0; j < dirs.length; j++)
 {
 //console.log(baseDir + "/" + dirs[j])
 var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + "/" + dirs[j]);
 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
 {
 if (files[i].endsWith(".css"))
 response.write('/' + dirs[j] + files[i] + '\n');
 }
 }

 var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + "/images");
 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
 {
 var s = fs.statSync(baseDir + '/images/' + files[i]);
 var s = s.mtime.getTime();
 response.write('/images/' + files[i] + '?v=' + s + '\n');
 }

 response.end();
 }*/

function welcomeFile(request, response)
{
    var filename = path.join(baseDir, "/welcome.html");
    //console.log(filename);

    fs.readFile(filename, function (err, fileData)
    {
        response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html", "Expires": -1, "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "Pragma": "no-cache" });

        var db = GLOBAL.getDb();

        db.open(function (err, db)
        {
            if (db == null)
            {
                fileData = ("" + fileData).replace("#news#", "");
                response.write(fileData.replace("#top#", ""));
                return;
            }

            db.collection("news", function (err, collection)
            {
                collection.find().toArray(function (err, data)
                {
                    var news = "<ul>";
                    data.sort(sortByDate);
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length && i < 5; i++)
                        news += "<li><b>" + data[i].date + ":</b> " + data[i].text + "</li>";
                    news += "</ul>";
                    fileData = ("" + fileData).replace("#news#", news);

                    db.collection("top", function (err, collection)
                    {
                        if (collection == null)
                        {
                            response.write(fileData.replace("#top#", ""));
                            response.end();
                            db.close();
                            return;
                        }
                        collection.findOne({_id: "user"}, function (err, data)
                        {
                            if (data == null)
                            {
                                response.write(fileData.replace("#top#", ""));
                                response.end();
                                db.close();
                                return;
                            }
                            var top = "<table>";
                            top += "<tr><td>Best players:</td><td>Level:</td></tr>";
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.level.length && i < 15; i++)
                            {
                                top += "<tr><td>" + data.level[i].username + "</td><td>" + data.level[i].value + "</td></tr>";
                            }
                            top += "</table>";
                            response.write(fileData.replace("#top#", top));
                            response.end();
                            db.close();
                            return;
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

function socketHandler(socket)
{
    GLOBAL.sockets[GLOBAL.sockets.length] = socket;
    socket.playerId = nextPlayerId++;
    socket.pingDate = new Date();
    socket.broadcast.emit('player_connect', {playerId: socket.playerId});
    socket.emit('player_id', {playerId: socket.playerId});

    for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL.socketFunctions.length; i++)
        eval("socket.on(GLOBAL.socketFunctions[" + i + "].name,function (data) { GLOBAL.socketFunctions[" + i + "].action(socket,data); });");
}

function socketPositionUpdate(socket, data)
{
    //console.log("ID: "+data.playerId+", X: "+data.x+", Y: "+data.y+" Z: "+data.z);
    // Send players within the areas
    for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL.sockets.length; i++)
    {
        if (GLOBAL.sockets[i].playerId == socket.playerId)
            continue;
        if (GLOBAL.sockets[i].position == undefined && Math.abs(data.ax) < 2 && Math.abs(data.ay) < 2)
        {
            GLOBAL.sockets[i].emit('player_position', data);
            continue;
        }
        if (GLOBAL.sockets[i].position == undefined || GLOBAL.sockets[i].position.ax == null)
            continue;
        if (Math.abs(GLOBAL.sockets[i].position.ax - data.ax) > 1 || Math.abs(GLOBAL.sockets[i].position.ay - data.ay) > 1)
            continue;
        GLOBAL.sockets[i].emit('player_position', data);
    }
    socket.position = data;
    for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL.updatePositionFunctions.length; i++)
        GLOBAL.updatePositionFunctions[i](socket, data);
}

function checkTimeout()
{
    /*var now = new Date();
     for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL.sockets.length; i++)
     {
     var diff = (now - GLOBAL.sockets[i].pingDate) / 1000;
     if (diff > 60 && GLOBAL.sockets[i].username != null && GLOBAL.sockets[i].username != undefined)
     {
     GLOBAL.sockets[i].emit('close_duplicate', {});
     GLOBAL.sockets[i].disconnect('unauthorized');
     }
     }*/
}

app.listen(config.port);
```

**config.js**:

```
var config = {
    dbName: "cubicverse",
    port: 80,
    title: "Cubicverse - Early Access",
    secureKey: "HjkhsdhsklKsha9i1390s"
};

module.exports = config;
```

With a currently running instance of the server.js process, the `sudo netstat -tulpn` output for the Ubuntu home computer is:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1423/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5940          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1679/teamviewerd
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10923/dnsmasq   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1362/postgres   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5433          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1361/postgres   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27036           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25647/steam     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:57343         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25647/steam     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58978           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21401/skype     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49828           0.0.0.0:*                           10923/dnsmasq   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58233           0.0.0.0:*                           1103/avahi-daemon: 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46077         0.0.0.0:*                           21401/skype     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           10888/libpepflashpl
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           1103/avahi-daemon: 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58978           0.0.0.0:*                           21401/skype     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27036           0.0.0.0:*                           25647/steam     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:56039           0.0.0.0:*                           25647/steam     
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           10923/dnsmasq   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           18145/dhclient  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           10911/cups-browsed
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                10888/libpepflashpl
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                1103/avahi-daemon: 
udp6       0      0 :::44104                :::*                                1103/avahi-daemon: 
udp6       0      0 :::44570                :::*                                10923/dnsmasq
```

On Ubuntu server:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1476/mongod     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32567/sshd      
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      19531/node      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Iptables and ufw both off on local machine:

```
peter@peter-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
peter@peter-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

The server process output on the Ubuntu server:

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01:~/cubicverse-newer/server# forever server.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
(node:19531) DeprecationWarning: process.EventEmitter is deprecated. Use require('events') instead.
(node:19531) DeprecationWarning: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use 'global'
```

And on the home Ubuntu PC:

```
peter@peter-HP-Notebook:~/cubicverse-new/server$ node server.js
(node:30406) DeprecationWarning: process.EventEmitter is deprecated. Use require('events') instead.
(node:30406) DeprecationWarning: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use 'global'
```

I tried running the process with elevated privileges on the home Ubuntu computer and get:

```
sudo node server.js
[sudo] password for peter: 
/home/peter/cubicverse-new/server/node_modules/socket.io/lib/store.js:35
Store.prototype.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype;

TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
   at Object.<anonymous> (/home/peter/cubicverse-
new/server/node_modules/socket.io/lib/store.js:35:41)
```

Which interestingly was the same error I was getting before I downgraded the node version on the home Ubuntu machine.

Any guesses as to what might be causing this?

Comment: Obviously I shall be changing the secure key :).

Comment: Unrelated tip: do not extend built-in prototypes. Also, avoid setting global variables (e.g. variables defined without `var`/`let`/`const` or attached explicitly via `GLOBAL.`/`global.`.

Comment: @mscdex ha! that's easily not the worst of the code! But it's not mine, I just have to get it working. I'll bear it in mind once I get on to the full rewrite stage, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I altered all instances of `EventEmitter.prototype` to instead use `require('events')`. Then I updated my node version back to 7.10.0 from version 6.9.1 which I'd downgraded it to (probably not necessary but worth doing anyway) and ran the server process again as root.

All working fine now.